# Pycharm cannot run debug Django Web App ,What is something wrong?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

***I cannot run debug for the Django project in Pycharm***
I got stuck on how to debug Django Python Project in Pycharm.
I don't know how I configure something in Pycharm incorrectly despite no problem in the other python project.

Is there anything for additional setting in Pycharm  Or further code in Django project file such as settings.py

In figure below, I do the following step.

1. Set Breakpoint in here
   2.Click Debug  in  view.py
2. debug stop at   **init**.py

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "Requested %s, but settings are not configured. "
                "You must either define the environment variable %s "
                "or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."
                % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
```

**Debugger never reaches my breakpoint at all.**

click to see picture [debuger in pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HhEh.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you don't have your app in the installed apps settings in settings.py.
I suppose your apps name is "templates"

If it is add it to installed apps by doing the following:
Under installed apps type,

`'templates.apps.templatesConfig'`

Hopefully this works... thx.

Comment: tell me , which place to put  'templates.apps.templatesConfig' ?

Comment: under settings, there will be a section called INSTALLED_APPS